# Static member initialization and specialization in template classes: differences between const and constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, constexpr, static-members

Experimentally, I know how to declare/initialize/define `static` data member of various kinds (mainly by reading the compiler diagnosis) yet I realize that I don't really understand the rules behind these mechanics and, noticibly the difference between `const` and `constexpr` `static` data member of template class.

Let say I have the following files.

TemplateODR.hpp

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct TData {
    static T m_Value;
    static constexpr T m_kValue = T(3.14);
};
```

TemplateDoubleSpecialization.hpp

```cpp
template <>
double TData<double>::m_Value;

// cannot gives a different specialization for the constexpr
// KO: template<> double TData<double>::m_kValue = 2.72;
```

TemplateDoubleSpecialization.cpp

```cpp
template <>
double TData<double>::m_Value = 3.14;
```

TestODRUse#N.cpp

```cpp
void TestODRUse#N() {
    std::cout << TData<double>::m_Value << '\n';
    std::cout << TData<double>::m_kValue << '\n';
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main() {
    TestODRUse1();
    TestODRUse2();  // testing for ODR violations
}
```

Other trivial header files and `#include` directives required as glue between the different files are omitted on purpose for clarity sake.
The full example is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YGTnjPTr3).

It seems that `constexpr` `static` data is a bit peculiar for template: a `const` `static` data member can be redefined for each specialization but the same does not apply to `constexpr` `static data`. We must resort, for instance, to
[Specialize static constexpr data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973717/specialize-static-constexpr-data-member). Why isn't it possible to manage a `const` and a `constexpr` static data member in the same way?

Comment: You are trying to compare apples to oranges. `const` to `constexpr` under the umbrella of being `static` data members. I drove to this conclusion because of your mention of *Why isn't it possible to manage a `const` and a `constexpr` `static` data member in the same way?*